# How to get the softlayer_ticket id after calling SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelItem(...)

Tags: php, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use SoftLayer API PHP library to call SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelItem(...)  or SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelService() to cancel the item.  I noticed there will be SoftLayer ticket generated on the SoftLayer customer portal after the SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelItem(...)  or SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelService() call.

The API returned result of SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelItem(...) or SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelService()  doesn't contain the result SoftLayer_Ticket information.

How can I use API to get  the SoftLayer_Ticket Id value associated with the SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelItem(...) or SoftLayer_billing_Item.cancelService() .

Is there any same php file I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the next objectMask in your code:

```
<?php
// Reference to the SL API client (It depends on your path installation) 
require_once ('C:\softlayer-api-php-client-master\src\SoapClient.php');
require_once ('C:\softlayer-api-php-client-master\src\Common\ObjectMask.php');

// Set these values with your valid information.
$username = 'set me';
$apiKey = 'set me';

$service = 'SoftLayer_Billing_Item';

// Set your billing item Id.
$billingItemId = 7883593;

// The client instantiation.
$client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient($service, $billingItemId, $username, $apiKey);

// The next lines belong to the creation of an object mask that retrieves aditional data
// contained in the objects retrieved.
$objectMask = new \SoftLayer\Common\ObjectMask();
$objectMask->cancellationRequests->ticket;
$client->setObjectMask($objectMask);

try 
{
    // Retrieving the configuration options for a SoftLayer_Hardware object.
    $cancellation_request = $client->getCancellationRequests();
    print_r($cancellation_request);
} 
catch (\Exception $e) 
{
    // Displaying if an error happened.
    die('Script failed, review the next message for further details: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

You can use the same objectMask in the same way for methods such as SoftLayer_Account::getLastCanceledBillingItem or SoftLayer::getLastCancelledServerBillingItem

Comment: Thank you Marcelo. How do I use object filter to get only the latest cancellation request if there're multile cancellation request on the billing item ?

Comment: I created my own sort function and solved the problem. thanks.